# Como acessar dados de um imput dinamico de um formulario com django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, python, django

Estou participando de um projeto em que estamos utilizando django. Eu criei um formulário com dois campos iniciais e podendo acrescentar mais dinamicamente usando javascript.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="panel-title"><b>Informe os Criterio:</b></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="add_field_criterio" value="adicionar">
        </div>
        <div id="grupo_criterio">
            <div>
            <label for="criterio" class="control-label">Criterio:</label>
                <input type="text" required  name="criterio[]" placeholder="Informe o nome do criterio">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="criterio" class="control-label">Criterio:</label>
                <input type="text" required name="criterio[]" placeholder="Informe o nome do criterio">
            </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var campos_criterio_max = 10;
var campos_alternativa_max = 10;    //max de 10 campos
var x = 3; // campos iniciais
var y = 3;
$('#add_field_criterio').click (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();     //prevenir novos clicks
    if (x <= campos_criterio_max) {
        $('#grupo_criterio').append('<div>\
        <label for="criterio" class="control-label">Criterio:</label>\
        <input type="text" required  name="criterio[]" placeholder="Informe o nome do criterio">\
        <a href="#" class="remover_campo_criterio btn btn-danger">Remover</a>\
        </div>');
        x++;
    }
});

// Remover o div anterior
$('#grupo_criterio').on("click",".remover_campo_criterio",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
});
```

Como eu acesso os elementos do método POST já que não haverá persistência de dados?

Comment: Podes explicar o que queres ir buscar e quando? Queres os valores dos inputs no momento do submit do form, é isso? o form é enviado via html ou queres impedir o envio e tratar os dados com JavaScript?

Comment: Eu quero receber os dados do formulário. O javascript que eu postei é para controlar a quantidade de inputs do formulário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digamos que você queira acessar a lista de critérios que o usuário adicionou:

1. Remova o `[]` do `criterio[]`. Quando é enviado inputs com mesmo `name` é criado uma lista automaticamente.

Agora é só acessar na view :

```
def foo(request):
       criterios = request.POST.get('criterio')
```

Comment: Obrigado! Vou testar.